# OkHttp POST using Android

Tags: android, okhttp

Im creating an Android app to log into my router to control the whitelist using OkHttp. However, for some reason I cannot get the POST request to be successful.

Ive used the code example on the github pages, but those came up with nothing. I also tried other examples online and read documentation, but it seems like nothing is working and my app just crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add crash stacktrace and your okHttp implementation

Comment: please post the github link

Comment: Hello, I realized that the problem is, I cant send POST or GET requests to 192.168.1.1